# eureka-1.11: DSO missing from command line

Tags: linux, gcc, opensuse

I've been trying to install eureka-1.11 program (DooM map editor for Linux) and when I ran make command, I got the error:

---

```
user_nout@linux-u90c:~/eureka-1.11-source> sudo make  
root's password:
```

> g++ obj_linux/editloop.o obj_linux/e_basis.o obj_linux/e_checks.o obj_linux/e_checks2.o obj_linux/e_cutpaste.o obj_linux/e_linedef.o obj_linux/e_loadsave.o obj_linux/e_nodes.o obj_linux/e_path.o obj_linux/e_sector.o obj_linux/e_things.o obj_linux/e_vertex.o obj_linux/im_arrows.o obj_linux/im_color.o obj_linux/im_img.o obj_linux/levels.o obj_linux/lib_adler.o obj_linux/lib_file.o obj_linux/lib_util.o obj_linux/main.o obj_linux/m_bitvec.o obj_linux/m_config.o obj_linux/m_files.o obj_linux/m_game.o obj_linux/m_keys.o obj_linux/m_select.o obj_linux/m_strings.o obj_linux/objects.o obj_linux/r_grid.o obj_linux/r_render.o obj_linux/sys_debug.o obj_linux/ui_about.o obj_linux/ui_browser.o obj_linux/ui_canvas.o obj_linux/ui_default.o obj_linux/ui_dialog.o obj_linux/ui_file.o obj_linux/ui_hyper.o obj_linux/ui_infobar.o obj_linux/ui_linedef.o obj_linux/ui_menu.o obj_linux/ui_misc.o obj_linux/ui_nombre.o obj_linux/ui_nodes.o obj_linux/ui_pic.o obj_linux/ui_prefs.o obj_linux/ui_replace.o obj_linux/ui_sector.o obj_linux/ui_scroll.o obj_linux/ui_sidedef.o obj_linux/ui_thing.o obj_linux/ui_tile.o obj_linux/ui_vertex.o obj_linux/ui_window.o obj_linux/w_loadpic.o obj_linux/w_flats.o obj_linux/w_sprite.o obj_linux/w_texture.o obj_linux/w_wad.o obj_linux/x_hover.o obj_linux/x_loop.o obj_linux/x_mirror.o obj_linux/glbsp/analyze.o obj_linux/glbsp/blockmap.o obj_linux/glbsp/glbsp.o obj_linux/glbsp/level.o obj_linux/glbsp/node.o obj_linux/glbsp/reject.o obj_linux/glbsp/seg.o obj_linux/glbsp/system.o obj_linux/glbsp/util.o obj_linux/glbsp/wad.o -o eureka -L /lib64 -lfltk_images -lfltk_gl -lfltk -lX11 -lXext -lXft -lfontconfig -lXinerama -lpng -ljpeg -lGL -lz -lm
>   /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib64/libfltk.a(Fl_Native_File_Chooser.o): undefined reference to symbol 'dlsym@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
>   /lib64/libdl.so.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   Makefile:158: recipe for target 'eureka' failed
>   make: *** [eureka] Error 1
>
> ---

*I was searching a lot about this type of error, but in each topic it was something different comparing to my problem.*

For note: **there is no configure file**; also I tried to put another LDFLAGS in make file.

**System: linux openSUSE Leap 42.1**

The part of the **makefile**, if needed:

---

```
INSTALL_DIR=$(PREFIX)/share/eureka

CXXFLAGS=$(OPTIMISE) -Wall -D$(OS)  \
     -Iglbsp_src  \
     -D_THREAD_SAFE -D_REENTRANT

LDFLAGS=-L/usr/X11R6/lib

LIBS= \
 -lfltk_images -lfltk_gl -lfltk  \
 -lX11 -lXext -lXft -lfontconfig -lXinerama  \
 -lpng -ljpeg -lGL -lz -lm
```

---

Any ideas how to overcome this issue?

Comment: May be the Suse 42.1 fltk will work : # `zypper in fltk-devel fltk-devel-static` ... That's fltk version 1.3.2  http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/leap/42.1/repo/oss/suse/x86_64/ ... Looks like you are using a home made version :  `/usr/local/lib64/libfltk.a`

Comment: Yes, that works! As you told, downloaded fltk by the given command and run 'make' again. Surprisingly, the problem was in fltk, I would never guess :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The question can be closed** - *[Knud Larsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4491743/knud-larsen)* has published an answer in the comment above.
All the thing was in not valid fltk on my system.

For reading the *full answer to my question*, see the comment, as I have already mentioned.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Testing eureka-111 with OpenSuse Leap 42.1 :

```
# zypper in gcc-c++ fltk-devel fltk-devel-static libXft-devel libjpeg8-devel libpng12-devel xdg-utils
```

`cd eureka-1.11-source/ && make` ... and the executable `eureka` is created.

---

P.S. : Reason for a difference with a manual build of fltk : The Suse 42.1 fltk packages were built with a different `configure` file ( Line 2685 edited ) :

```
-            DSOCOMMAND="\$(CXX) \$(DSOFLAGS) -Wl,-soname,\$@ \$(LDLIBS) -shared -fPIC $DEBUGFLAG -o"
+            DSOCOMMAND="\$(CXX) -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--no-undefined \$(DSOFLAGS) -Wl,-soname,\$@ \$(LDLIBS) -shared -fPIC $DEBUGFLAG -o"
```

Ref. the patch `fltk-1.3.2-underlinking.patch` in the source SRPM, fltk-1.3.2-9.2.src.rpm

---